# Run javascript after ng-view loads or directive loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-view

I have some javascript I need to run after a particular template rendered in ng-view finishes loading.

If it's the first page to load this works:

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

The code is being executed in a controller for the template so it is outside of the main html file. I have also tried nesting it in a directive under link: so that it won't run until after the directive is loaded, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the snippet I need to run:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the following:

```
$scope.$on("$viewContentLoaded",function() {
 // some code to run after ng-view loaded completlly ...
});
```